# comparing raster values over one specific transect

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, 3d-analyst, comparison, cross-section

I have a raster with water temperature data.
I used various kinds of filters over it (smoothing, sharpening filter etc.) in various combination. I want to compare the results, to check which combination is the best for differentiating water spots of different temperatures. I wanted to do cross sections (transects) in few places that interest me and compare differences in values distributions on the line from point A to B.

I looked at various forums and I'm starting to wonder is it even possible?
If anyone knows how to do this (or maybe there is another way)?

Comment: do yes have the 3D Analyst extension available?

Comment: @luke Yes, although I've never used it before

Comment: Then the [Stack Profile](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q9000000mm000000) tool may be of use.

Answer (score 1):

As commented by @Luke:

> the [Stack
>   Profile](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00q9000000mm000000)
>   tool may be of use

That tool:

> Creates a table and optional graph denoting the profile of line
>   features over one or more multipatch, raster, TIN, or terrain
>   surfaces.